# Is it possible to visually design a custom component at design time?

Tags: delphi, delphi-2010, tframe

I am venturing into making my own components in Delphi. I'm having difficulty getting started with component development.

I want to make a composite control ie a control made up of several other controls, eg like an address form or something like that.

I am descending from TWinControl. Would that be considered to be the correct choice?

The main thing is, I cannot see a way to visually design the component in D2010. Is this possible? eg drop some text boxes onto your component, as you would with a form. I'm hoping I don't have to hand code all the visual aspects to my own components..

Also any good links on delphi component dev would be very much appreciated - esp for composite controls. The docs are not A1, its a struggle. I searched a lot already, I'm still going nowhere fast.

Comment: No, custom components are written in code. But maybe you could simply use a `TFrame`?

Comment: Yes I think TFrame (which is err... new to me) is the way indeed to go. Ty.

Answer (score 7, accepted):

If you're making something with multiple controls such as an address form, you might consider making it a frame instead of a control.  Frames can be designed like windows, and re-used.

Comment: Thats music to my ears. I been using TPanel temporarily just to group things together before I made them into proper re-usable objects, I was unaware of TFrame. I knew there must be something, else it is not all that RAD! I'm hoping TFrames can be re-used on different forms, it looks that way from my initial reading. Thanks.

Comment: You can re-use them on different forms - they're a class like any other!  Drop one of the frames you've made on two different forms to try it out - they will work like dropping two of any individual component.

Answer (score 3):

You'll have to describe it in code to compile, but you can use a trick to design the component visually at first.

Put a TPanel  on the form, and let that stand for the base control.  Arrange your sub-controls, then get the properties from text view.  GExperts adds a menu option that will convert controls on a form to code to generate them automatically, making this step a lot easier.

Answer (score 2):

Read my bog article on [using Frames as Visual Components - don't forget your spring](http://wiert.wordpress.com/2009/07/16/delphi-frames-as-visual-components-dont-forget-your-sprig/).
It is very easy: put everything on your Frame, register it as a component, register the sprig, and don't forget that at design time 'Visible=False' is being ignored.

I just explained this yesterday during my preconference workshop at the [DelphiLive! conference](http://www.delphilive.com/) :-)

--jeroen